# Interface method is not invoked on all implementations

Tags: java, android, interface

I have an interface that is like so:

```
public interface ISignaller {
    void onPublishMessage(String message);
}
public interface ISignaller2 {
    void onPublishMessage(String message);
}
```

And a service that uses this ISignaller

```
public class SignallerService {
    ISignalR listener;
    
    public SignallerService(ISignalR listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    
    public void start() {
        // ... some method here
        var someVar = someMethod();
        if (someVar) {
            listener.onPublishMessage("THIS IS CALLED");
        }
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ISignaller
{
    SignallerService ss = new SignallerService(this);
    
    public void start() {
        ss.start();
    }

    public void setPublisher(ISignaller2 publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
    
    // THIS GETS CALLED
    @Override
    public void onPublishMessage(String message) {
        this.publisher.onPublishMessage(message);
    }
}

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements ISignaller {

    // THIS IS NOT CALLED
    @Override
    public void onPublishMessage(String message) {
        Log.i("TAG", message);
    }
    
    MainActivity mMainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
    mMainActivity.setPublisher(this);
    mMainActivity.start();
}
```

Why is it that the override onPublishMesesage in MainActivity gets called but not in the FirstFragment?

Comment: I don't even see an instantiation of FirstFragment. Where do you use it?

Comment: @Stultuske I am using navigation graph sir.

Comment: OK? and how does that answer my question? In your activity you do this: SignallerService ss = new SignallerService(this); -> only the instance of MainActivity is sent to the Service, not an instance of your Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

When creating instance of `SignallerService` you're passing activity's instance into constructor, so it's used as a listener, and get's all the callbacks. You should either propagate callback to the Fragment from the activity (from within the activity's `onPublishMessage` search the instance of the fragment and call it's callback method manually), or register Fragment's instance as a listener (pass it into `SignallerService` constructor). In your current implementation, your service knows only about activity (as it's the only listener, who called the constructor and passed itself as listener for future events)

Comment: What you said actually make a lot of sense.  I edited my question and I made it work with it. Only, the way I have done it, is it correct? Basically, I created a new interface and have that implement by the FirstFragment and succeeding fragmets then in my MainActivity, invoke the method that needs to be published to the other fragments.

Comment: "from within the activity's onPublishMessage search the instance of the fragment and call it's callback method manually " => Maybe this is better... But how do I find the instance of the fragment when the way I load my FirstFragment is  through "navigation graph" -> "app:startDestination="@id/FirstFragment""

On the way I "solved it" I am suspecting that this may cause memory leak. When I jump to another fragment, will the implementation in the FirstFragment be disposed?

Comment: Well, storing the instance of the activity in the SignalingService might cause context leak. IMO it would be a little more efficient to pass the listener into SignalingService via setter (not constructor). This way, you can use utilize fragment's lifecycle callback to set fragment as a listener, and remove itself (passing null into listener, for instance) as a listener when fragment is no longer available (after onDestroyView() for instance).

Comment: Hmmm. You're right. I'll make the adjustments. Thank you. +1!